# Write terminal output results to file in php

Tags: php, system, output

I have run my commands using system and i would like for it copy the terminal results to a file called output.txt. When I run my php script on the browser it displays the result but not in the output.txt the file is empty.

```
echo '<pre>';

$last_line = system('ruby /home/simon/ruby-grok/examples/result.rb', $retval);

echo '</pre>';

$out = fopen('output.txt', 'w'); //output handler
fputs($out,$last_line); //writing output operation
fclose($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code seems fine. 
Does script have the permission to write in that specific file? And can you try instead of

```
$out = fopen('output.txt', 'w'); //output handler
fputs($out,$last_line); //writing output operation
fclose($out);
```

to put this:

```
file_put_contents('output.txt',$last_line);
```

### edit:

btw i forgot to ask. what output your browser displays? is there any data in $out variable?

Comment: On my browser it displays the results. It does write but it only writes the last line of the result, is there a way to write in line by line

Comment: line by line no.. but you can use exec($cmd . " > $pathToFile"); instead of system command - this way system will write whole output directly to file on given path

Comment: This will not display the output on the browser. I would like it to display on browser and written in the a file. There should another way I could try. exec seems not to work but the displaying on the browser system seems to work.

Comment: then use shell_exec - this will return output. put returned value in the variable and echo it to browser and save it with file_put_contents

Answer (score 0):

Using backticks is much better.

```
$variable = `ls -l`;
```

and then:

```
$out = fopen('output.txt', 'w'); //output handler

fputs($out,$variable); //writing output operation

fclose($out);
```

or:

```
file_put_content('output.txt',$variable);
```